# I have a text column in pandas, and i have a list containing some words.I need to match the text in each row with the word in list and keep them

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the column `train['final_input_text']` containing  text values. I have a set of words in a list, which i need to match with 
`train['final_input_text'].values`, if it matches keep the words in `train['final_input_text']`.

```
train['final_input_text'].values[1] = 'students would rather school home sometimes high poverty'
```

I tried using loops , but was unable to arrive

```
text_df=train['final_input_text'].values
```

I need to keep only those words in `train[final_input_text]` which matches the words in my list, which has ~9k words.

Comment: Vineet: Give an sample input row, sample words of list and sample output

Comment: train[final_input_text].values[2]is ''students come late class go lunchroom arriving school eat breakfast unable '                                                 & my word list is list of words(strings) of size 9,324

Comment: I hope the below answers helped you, if not..please update the question and not in the comments, it is confusing in the comment section

Answer (score 1):

This will create data frame only with words from list

```
train = train[train['final_input_text'].isin(words_list)]
```

Answer (score 0):

if the words are in list is unigram you follow this method:

```
 list_words = ['word1','word2','word3','word4']
 for x in range(len(train)):
     for w in list_words:
         if w in train['final_input_text'][x]:
            train['word in final_input'][x] = w
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function split to be able to compare your text with specific words. Then use the join function to aggregate the words you found matching back to a single string.

Here is a working example :

```
df_text = pd.DataFrame({'final_input_text':['hello my name is Bob','I like the name Bob']})

In [1] : print(df_text)
Out[1] : final_input_text
0   hello my name is Bob
1   I like the name Bob

words_to_match = ['name', 'Bob', 'hello', 'world']

for index, row in df_text.iterrows():
    words_to_keep = []
    for word in row[0].split(' '):
        if word in words_to_match :
            words_to_keep.append(word + ' ')
    df_text.loc[index, 'final_input_text']= ''.join(words_to_keep)

In [2] : print(df_text)
Out[2] :    final_input_text
0   hello name Bob
1   name Bob
```